# How to change the section's content format?

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I have written a latex file including multiple layers of sectioning. What I want to do is change the tabbing/location of each layer. And maybe also change the font or something.

But the problem I have, is that I know how to do it section by section, but not how to change this for the layers in general.

The only things I found is how to change the section headers in general, but not the text underneath (as well).

This is part of the file:

```
\documentclass[12pt, fleqn, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\title{xxx}
\date{xxx}
\author{xxx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\chapter{Geordende Verzamelingen}

\section{Definities}

\subsection{Geordende Verzamelingen}
This needs to be tabbed to the right, bold and dark blue

\subsubsection{Voorbeeld}
This needs to be double tabbed to the right, italic and light blue
```

Thank you for reading this and I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Welcome, what you wants depends on the documentclass in use. Please show us a minimal working example to reproduce your current setup.

Comment: @Johannes_B Hee, thanks for checking in to it. I revised my question, but it doesn't really matter what kind of documentclass to use. I like book and article as well (only thing is that I have to change some minor things, but thats allright)

Comment: Not relevant, but you might be interested in the `\land` and `\lor` commands (Logical AND; Logical OR).

Comment: As for the need for an MWE, it very much does matter what documentclass you use :) there are general ways to do this sort of thing, but some of the more advanced classes (KOMA\*, memoir) have their own way of doing things.

Comment: If the class wouldn't be important, i wouldn't ask for it. For the generic standard classes, `titlesec`  is the package of choice.

Comment: @immaan: The class is always important!

Comment: My apologies for not making myself clear. I do not mean the documentclass is not important in general, I mean that I don't mind if I have to change it because I am just using a standard one.

Comment: @SeanAllred I now know there are more ways of doing that, for the time I wrote it, that was the first thing I came across. Do you think I need to revise that? And if yes, why?

Comment: @Johannes_B I looked in to `titlesec` but is that not only for the titles/headers? (as mentioned I want to change the text underneath the sections) If not, do you know where I have too look to find an answer to that?

Comment: @immaan: Which text underneath the section (titles)? The text you're writing? That's basically up to you

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think that every text following `section` is supposed to be red and everything following `subsection` to be in italics. One def for the whole doc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, but I want to be able to change that

Comment: @immaan: Change to what?

Comment: the sectioning commands are just that -- commands -- and they have no effect on the text that follows.  to effect such a change, you need to enclose the text in an environment, or at least a group.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for the command. This is all I need to know. So I have to group all the separate sections individually?

Comment: @immaan: Your post is totally unclear. There's a non-working fragment of a document and you're not really clearifing what you want to change into which direction.

Comment: yes, each "unit" must be grouped individually, to properly delineate the scope.  it might be easiest to define environments that take the (sub)section heading as an argument.  this should be relatively easy if you never use an optional argument to the heading, but if you do use optional arguments, things get messy.  (haven't time to work out a reliable answer; just back from holiday with a huge backlog of demands.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton You already helped me out a lot, so thanks. I'll just get on it!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thank you for your concern. However, thanks to barbara I now have an answer to my question. Still I would like to know what I should have asked the community to make myself more clear. Can you derive a good/understandable question from the answers barbara gave? (So I have a lead on how to formulate my questions in the future)

Comment: in your example code, you might have put a comment under the `\section` line saying `% the following text until the next header should be ...` and similarly for the `\subsection`.  i had to read the comments to figure out what was likely to be wanted, and then it was still a (lucky) guess.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes I understand, that would be more clear! tnx

Comment: @immaan -- another possibility might be to change the title to "changing the format of the contents of a section".

Comment: @barbarabeeton so shall I change all of that, of just delete the post. Since it was not a strong question and the answer is simply no it can't

Comment: @immaan -- i suggest to change the title.  (enough discussion; the notice to move to chat has emerged, and i don't think it's worth that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For article class, the `\section` command (for example) is defined using

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

where `\@startsection` is documented in `source2e` (see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e?lang=en).  (Not intended as an answer, but too complicated for a comment.)